# phonegap android returning to native app from remote server

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, pageload

I have a phonegap app on android that runs in a remote server. On the main page I do:

```
window.location.href=startUrl+"./main.html"+params;
```

This loads the main.html page that runs on a server.

From there I'm trying to return to the index page (the native one), but I don't know how to do this. I'm trying this:

```
window.location.href= 'file:///android_asset/www/index.html';
```

But does not work.

Any ideas of how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
navigator.app.loadUrl('file:///android_asset/www/index.html');
```